# Categorizing multiple entries in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style, legend, classification, rule-based

I am trying to categorize a polygon layer with several buildings, by the number of floors.

I want to aggregate by classes like this way:

```
1 floor = 1 to 2 floors;
2 floors = 1 to 2 floors;
3 floors = 3 to 4 floors;
4 floors = 3 to 4 floors;
5 floors = 5 to 6 floors;
6 floors = 5 to 6 floors
```

But by just simply entering the classification/legend I want (by hand) I get this result, which as you can see it duplicates the results:

[image]

Do I have to use "Ruled-based" and if so... how?

Comment: I vote for the reopening since the OP has just applied the suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `Rule-based` renderer. Following your data, something like that:

[image]

Click on the `+` button for adding a rule and then insert the custom expression (as indicated in the red box above).

Remember also to click on the `Apply` button for applying the style.

Comment: I just edited my comment, with a more complex answer. Can you help me? Thank you in advance for you patience :)

Comment: @M_M, you are looking for help for another issue that, as you wrote in your edited question, is applied to another case. Only one question per question is allowed in GIS SE, so the best practice would be the following: 1) remove the last edits on your question and ask a new separate question where you describe the new issue; 2) mark my answer as _accepted_ if it helped you to solve the current problem. Once you have asked the new question, I will try to give you a help! =)

Comment: Yes, thank you! Probably because I'm new here :) Just editing! Thank you

Comment: @M_M well done, thanks! If I'm able to solve your new issue, I will give my solution!